# C How to assign a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have a method that has pointers and I want to put it in another pointer based on input.

This is an over simplified version:

```
struct people
{
    char sName[20];
    int nAge;
};

void printDetails(struct people person)
{
    printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d\n", person.sName, person.nAge);
}

void changeAge(struct people *person1, struct people *person2, int nNewAge, int nPerson)
{
    /// I know that this is wrong. I don't know how to implement this. This is my best try.
    struct people *personToBeModified;
    if (nPerson == 1)
        *personToBeModified = *&(*person1);
    else if (nPerson == 2)
        *personToBeModified = *&(*person2);

    (*personToBeModified).nAge = nNewAge;
}
void main() 
{
    struct people person1 = {"Yeet", 18};
    struct people person2 = {"Yeetboii", 18};
    changeAge(&person1, &person2, 20, 2);
    printDetails(person1);
    printDetails(person2); 
}
```

What I want to happen in the ***changeAge*** is to be able to put a person object(an argument) into a person object defined inside the function and be able to modify it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign to `*personToBeModified` when you do because `personToBeModified` doesn't point anywhere yet.  Also, when `&` immediately precedes `*` they cancel each other out, so `*&(*person1)` is the same as `*person1`

Assigning to a pointer is like assigning to anything else.  Here, you are simply assigning the address of the appropriate person to `personToBeModified`:

```
if (nPerson == 1)
    personToBeModified = person1;
else if (nPerson == 2)
    personToBeModified = person2;
```

Answer (score 4):

`*` and `&` negate each other, so you shouldn't use them together. Also you don't want to make a pointer point to another pointer, you want to point to the same address in the memory. So this will do the trick:

```
void changeAge(struct people *person1, struct people *person2, int nNewAge, int nPerson)
{
    struct people *personToBeModified;
    if (nPerson == 1)
        personToBeModified = person1;
    else if (nPerson == 2)
        personToBeModified = person2;

    (*personToBeModified).nAge = nNewAge;
}
```

Comment: How about `negate` instead of `kills`.

Comment: `(*personToBeModified).nAge = nNewAge;`---->    `personToBeModified -> nAge = nNewAge;`